# Word for "can be used again with entertainment"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

*The title may be misleading as I had trouble summarizing the question in a phrase.*

I'm looking for a word to mean "usable again", referring to a mobile app. I'm looking for something along the lines of "replayable" for games.

I want to reword the phrase "give both hardcore & casual fans a reason to keep coming back" to make it sound more technical, preferably something along the lines of "to provide *word here* to the app". If I were to refer to a game, I would word it as "to add replay value to the game".

Thank you very much.

Comment: Reusability.....?

Comment: @WS2 I was hoping for something to mean that the users are entertained by using the app, that's why they use it again. Preferably something like how one reuses his TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compelling? or Addictive? or Compulsive?

Comment: Compelling fits my requirements. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Although it can hold that definition, **compelling** isn't really used that way in American English nowdays, it's used mostly like "convincing" or "moving", as in "a moving argument".

Answer (score 2):

**[replayability:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/replayability)**

> *(video games)* replay value
>
> *This new game is reported to have excellent replayability, with many features that draw players into the game's engaging world.*

---

**[replay value:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_value)**

> Replay value is a term found in combination with video games, but it may be also used to describe other kinds of games, movies, music, or theater plays.
>
> In video games, the term replay value is used to describe the **entertainment value of playing a game more than once**.

---

In gaming forums, people mostly seek for games with the **most replay value**. Sometimes they use **replayable** too, though it is more like a neologism.

Comment: +1 **Replay value** is actually the technical term used by game developers.

Answer (score 0):

Engaging, involving, absorbing perhaps?